# Why is firefox complaining that it can't open my profile?

Tags: firefox, user-profiles, firefox-profile

I'm trying to get Firefox working with multiple profiles (under Fedora 33). This isn't a new configuration; I've had this all working successfully in the past, but suddenly Firefox seems unhappy. If I try to start Firefox with an explicit profile, like this:

```
firefox --profile default
```

It complains:

```
Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.
```

Even though:

- A profile named `default` exists and is visible in the profile manager.
- An entry for the `default` profile exists in `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`:

  ```
  [Profile1]
  Name=default
  IsRelative=1
  Path=8hiuv29u.default
  ```
- The named directory exists:

  ```
  $ ls -ld ~/.mozilla/firefox/8hiuv29u.default
  drwx------ 11 lars lars 4096 Jan 12 16:13 /home/lars/.mozilla/firefox/8hiuv29u.default
  ```
- If I run `firefox` without any additional argument, it brings up the profile manager. If I select `default` and then `Start Firefox`, it opens the browser as expected.

This is happening with multiple profiles; not just the `default` profile. These are all profiles that were just created; initially, I thought perhaps there were some issues with stale profiles so I deleted all the old profiles and re-created them.

Most of the solutions I've found online boil down to "delete your profiles and re-create them", but I've done that without success. Absent a solution, suggestions on getting more (any!) verbose debug information out of Firefox to help diagnose the problem are also appreciated.

---

Update: just to make sure there wasn't something weird hanging around from a prior install, I tried this:

```
$ rm -rf $HOME/.mozilla $HOME/.cache/mozilla
```

And then started up the profile manager:

```
$ firefox --profilemanager
```

Create two new profiles (`default` and `work`), and then tried:

```
$ firefox --profile default
```

And that still produces the same error.

Comment: What Linux distro are you running?  (I wonder if your problem is related to selinux?)   If you (temporarily) do a "sudo setenforce 0" does it start working?  Also, what happens if you "sudo chown -R lars.lars /~lars/.mozilla"  - I wonder if its a permissions problem on .mozilla - although I suspect this is somewhat unlikely.

Comment: As noted in the question, I'm running Fedora 33. Since I deleted and then re-created the profiles, I am confident the permissions are correct, especially since everything works correctly when started from the profile manager. I explicitly reset the permissions *anyway*, and there was no change in behavior.  Selinux is disabled on this system.

Comment: I think you may have not read to the bottom of the question: I completely deleted the `.mozilla` folder, removing *all* firefox profiles, `profiles.ini`, and everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `--profile` doesn't take the name of a profile ; instead, it takes a *path*. I realize this is included in the help output, but it wasn't obvious and I only noticed the behavior when running `strace`.  Compare this `strace` output, from running `firefox -profile default` (where my cwd is `~/.mozilla`):

```
925559 stat("/home/lars/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=307, ...}) = 0
925559 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/lars/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini", O_RDONLY) = 12
925559 getcwd("/home/lars/.mozilla", 4096) = 20
925559 lstat("/home/lars/.mozilla/default", 0x7ffd7af11200) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

With this, the result of running `firefox -profilemanager` and choosing the default profile:

```
927814 stat("/home/lars/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=299, ...}) = 0
927814 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/lars/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini", O_RDONLY) = 13
927814 stat("/home/lars/.mozilla/firefox/x4mpd3cq.default", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
```

Everything works if I provide an explicit path, like this:

```
firefox --profile ~/.mozilla/firefox/x4mpd3cq.default/
```

There is a separate option, `-P`, that accepts a profile name, so this also works:

```
firefox -P default
```

Answer (score -1):

Why is it doing it? I dunno. You have shown that the profile folder is owned by you; have you ensured that all contained files are as well? It's a long shot, but perhaps `sudo chown -R lars:lars ~/.mozilla/firefox/8hiuv29u.default` makes a difference.

Is it fixable? Try this:

1. Create a new folder, say `~/.mozilla/firefox/8hiuv29u.default/Lars`.
2. Create a single file in that folder: `touch ~/.config/Firefox/Lars/prefs.js`. No need to put any content in it.
3. Start Firefox with the profile manager, create a new profile:

   1. Name it "Lars", but don't click "Finish" just yet!
   2. Click "Choose Folder", and navigate to `~/.mozilla/firefox/Lars`.
   3. Click "Finish".
4. Start Firefox with that profile (this should create a bunch of additional files), then quit Firefox again.
5. Copy (don't move!) the files from the old profile to the new directory. Ideally, start by copying only `prefs.js` (your settings) and `places.sqlite` (your bookmarks).

   1. For each individual `.xpi` file within `~/.mozilla/firefox/8hiuv29u.default/extensions`, either double-click the file (it should open in Firefox) or drag it into the browser window to re-install your old addons. (Pro tip: I would use this opportunity to identify what's what, rename the source `.xpi` files, and keep a backup copy of them "for next time".)
   2. To restore your addon settings, close Firefox and then copy over `~/.mozilla/firefox/8hiuv29u.default/extension-preferences.json` and/or `~/.mozilla/firefox/8hiuv29u.default/extensions.json`/ and/or `~/.mozilla/firefox/8hiuv29u.default/extension-settings.json` (I don't recall what's what of these).
   3. You *may* also have luck copying other items, but this may also give problems due to the existence of the old profile name within some of the files. Caveat lector.

In the future, after a fresh Firefox install, follow steps 1, 2, and 3, and then just replace the entire profile folder with the one from your latest backup.

Comment: Since I have removed the entire `~/.mozilla` folder and allowed the browser to re-recreate, I am confident it is neither a permissions nor ownership issue.